# adding selected product to a table in php

Tags: php, html

I have 3 select forms  and an addToCart button in the page. I can get data from db to show products in the select forms, there is no problem. When user clicks addToCart button, I need to get selected values from the select forms and write them to a table in the same page. Here is the select forms and button. Can u help me to write a function in php to do this.

```
 <select class="form-control" id="chooseItem">
  <option disabled selected>Buradan Seç...</option>

<?php

  $sql="SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY productName ASC";
  $query = mysql_query($sql);
  $optionBeverage= '';

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $optionBeverage .= '<option value =  "'.$row['productName'].'">'.$row['productName'].'</option>';
  }

?>
<?php echo $optionBeverage; ?>

 </select> 
 <h3>Sandviçler & Hamur İşleri</h3>
 <select class="form-control" id="chooseItem">
  <option disabled selected>Buradan Seç...</option>

<?php

  $sql="SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY productName ASC";
  $query = mysql_query($sql);
  $optionSandwich= '';

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   $optionSandwich .= '<option value = "'.$row['productName'].'">'.$row['productName'].'</option>';
  }

?>
<?php echo $optionSandwich; ?>

 </select>
 <h3>Tatlılar</h3>
 <select class="form-control" id="chooseItem">
  <option disabled selected>Buradan Seç...</option>

<?php

  $sql="SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY productName ASC";
  $query = mysql_query($sql);
  $optionDesert= '';

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   $optionDesert .= '<option value = "'.$row['productName'].'">'.$row['productName'].'</option>';
  }

?>
<?php echo $optionDesert; ?>

 </select>
 <p>
  <br>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  onclick="xx">Sepete Ekle</button>
 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need javascript at here to get value of select.

```
$('#addtocart').on('click',function(){ //on add to cart button clicked

   selectedOption=$( "#myselect option:selected" ).text(); get value myselect's value

   //write selectedOption anywhere you want
   //Example: $('#myDiv').html(selectedOption);   

});
```

Make each selects id (chooseItem) unique.

If you need write it to database, use ajax.

Comment: I did that but nothing happens;    $('#addToCartButton').click(function(){
    
        var toAdd=$('#chooseItem :selected').text();
        $('#orderList').append('<p>' + toAdd + '</p>');
        
        
    });

Comment: You have multiple chooseItem id at selectboxs. Change ids. Check errors at firebug or dev tools console.

Comment: I changed them, there is only one "chooseItem". Actually, I tried a lot of things. I think my button click event does not work. Do u have any idea about the reason?

Comment: Firebug is good for debugging. Try this $( "#chooseItem  option:selected" ).text();

Comment: thnks, I solved the problem. My script page did not load properly. I add <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>